# Is it correct to use "City Name-area" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Is it possible to use this: "**Phoenix-area** businesses" instead of "businesses in Phoenix" or "Phoenix businesses?"

Comment: Yes, it's quite common. Though there are local variations that one would be wise to learn, like _Chicagoland_.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely correct to do so.

But, as John Lawler points out there are often regional variations.  *Chicagoland*, *Tri-State Area* (New York, New Jersey, and Connecticut surrounding New York City), and many others.

Phoenix for example seems to prefer Phoenix-Metro(politan) Area.  [Here is an example.](http://azmetro.com/phxmetro.html)

The general implication of adding -area to the end of a city name is that it includes the surrounding region, (suburbs, perhaps).